# Boost Spirit parser crashes on input

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit

I have a boost spirit parser that uses the `qi::double_` numeric parser. I have case where the user's data contains a uuid string:

`"00573e443ef1ec10b5a1f23ac8a69c43c415cedf"`

And I am getting a crash inside the spirit `pow10_helper()` function below. Testing some more it appears to happen for any string starting with a number followed by `e` and another number. For example `1e999` also crashes. To reproduce the crash, try:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
int main()
{
    double x;
    std::string s = "1e999";
    auto a = s.begin();
    auto b = s.end();
    qi::parse(a, b, qi::double_, x); // <--- crash/assert in debug mode
}
```

I'm using spirit due to it's raw performance (`qi::double_` is roughly 2x faster than `strtod()`). My question is, is there a way to workaround this limitation? Switching to a slower parser will be painful, but let me know if you have particular suggestions.

The relevant boost code is crashing (`boost/spirit/home/support/detail/pow10.hpp`) for reference:

```
template <>
struct pow10_helper<double>
{
    static double call(unsigned dim)
    {
        static double const exponents[] =
        {
            1e0,   1e1,   1e2,   1e3,   1e4,   1e5,   1e6,   1e7,   1e8,    1e9,
            ...
            1e300, 1e301, 1e302, 1e303, 1e304, 1e305, 1e306, 1e307, 1e308,
        };
        BOOST_ASSERT(dim < sizeof(exponents)/sizeof(double));
        return exponents[dim]; // <--- crash here, dim is 999 which is >308
    }
};
```

As a side note, this seems like a *huge* bug in the in spirit implementation. You should be able to easily crash any spirit app that parses doubles by passing in a dummy input value like `1e999`.

Comment: spot on, also about the security implications. The good news is it's an assert, but still. Large liability

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue and has been fixed in 1_57_0 AFAIR

Here's the mailing list discussion about it:

- http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/bug-in-quot-double-quot-parser-causes-program-abort-minimum-example-provided-td4668308.html

On November 7th Joel de Guzman wrote:

> This is now fixed in the develop branch along with a whole slew of 
>   improvements in floating point precision parsing (the corner cases). 
>   There are some backward incompatible changes, but it should only 
>   affect those who are using the real parser policies, in patrticular, 
>   those who specialize parse_frac_n. The changes will be documented in 
>   due time.

Comment: And in particular, the test case that is included above will now produce `inf` instead of an assertion.